# Splunk Re Installation Error

Tags: splunk

I am trying to  re installed Splunk 6.2 in windows machine. But I am not able to uninstall the old one from control panel.  When I try to repair  the installed Splunk instance it gives error "Fatal error during installation".

So now I am not able to uninstall or repair the Splunk.

Answer (score 0):

Splunk is a multi-platform product. As a result all it really does is make a few registry entries in Windows when it installs. If you need to reinstall, just get the installer package and do it. You can remove the registry entries if you wish. If you wish you can simply delete the old Splunk folder and its contents before you reinstall it. Usually I simply rename the original splunk folder and then install a clean package. that way if I have anyting in Splunk\etc\apps that I absolutely want to keep I have it and can copy it to the new install.